# How to solve Android View Pager Out of memory Exception?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, out-of-memory

I am using android [auto scroll view pager](https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager) for infinite scrolling. I have four fragments as view pager elements. Out of these first three contains an Imageview and the final one contains a Listview. Each image in fragment has a size of about 260KB. While running this page about 5 minutes, I am getting out of memory exception and thereby inflate exception.

I added `android:largeHeap="true"`
in manifest. I tried both `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Can anyone suggest what else I should do? Is there anything that I have to avoid?

Logcat :

```
02-05 22:24:58.649: D/dalvikvm(2006): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 12K, 18% free 40067K/48460K, paused 75ms, total 75ms
02-05 22:24:58.649: E/dalvikvm-heap(2006): Out of memory on a 1030552-byte allocation.
02-05 22:24:58.659: I/dalvikvm(2006): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
02-05 22:24:58.659: I/dalvikvm(2006):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40c959a0 self=0x4521b010
02-05 22:24:58.659: I/dalvikvm(2006):   | sysTid=2006 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1074267100
02-05 22:24:58.659: I/dalvikvm(2006):   | state=R schedstat=( 66536119633 40132743333 68805 ) utm=6247 stm=406 core=0
02-05 22:24:58.659: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-05 22:24:58.669: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
02-05 22:24:58.679: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
02-05 22:24:58.679: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
02-05 22:24:58.679: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
02-05 22:24:58.689: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
02-05 22:24:58.689: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
02-05 22:24:58.689: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
02-05 22:24:58.689: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-05 22:24:58.689: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
02-05 22:24:58.699: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
02-05 22:24:58.709: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-05 22:24:58.709: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
02-05 22:24:58.709: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
02-05 22:24:58.709: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-05 22:24:58.709: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-05 22:24:58.709: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at com.example.test.MFirstFragment.onCreateView(WelcomeFragment1.java:29)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1240)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:612)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:139)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:804)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:433)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:405)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:397)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager.scrollOnce(AutoScrollViewPager.java:169)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager$MyHandler.handleMessage(AutoScrollViewPager.java:236)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-05 22:24:58.719: I/dalvikvm(2006):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-05 22:24:58.739: D/skia(2006): --- decoder->decode returned false
02-05 22:24:58.739: D/AndroidRuntime(2006): Shutting down VM
02-05 22:24:58.739: W/dalvikvm(2006): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c94930)
02-05 22:24:59.049: E/AndroidRuntime(2006): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 22:24:59.049: E/AndroidRuntime(2006): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-05 22:24:59.049: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
02-05 22:24:59.049: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-05 22:24:59.049: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
```

Comment: `Recycled` your imageView `Bitmap` after used.

Comment: i have static images that are in resource folder. should i recycle?

Comment: it usually happens when the images are too big. if they are not, check if you are reusing elements in your custom listview

Comment: in listview there is no images. Three static images are of size  about 250KB.

Answer (score 3):

First off, do not use android:largeHeap="true" in the first go. It is to be used perhaps as a last resort, after exhausting all other ways.

So what is the way out? The lesson that I learnt the hard way is, "DO NOT REINVENT THE WHEEL". Use 3rd-party libraries like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or the like to get out of the situation like this. And additional bonanza is that you're code is much maintainable. Glide, for instance, is fast in compressing and loading the images into the ImageView. And it's API, is really neat.

Comment: Thanks ... you solved my problem ... the error disappeared when i used Picasso librarty

Answer (score 0):

add onDestroy method in pageradapter(or any of your page adapter) so that your previous imageviews will be going for garbage collector and free memory for new one.

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object o) {
    Log.d("main", "garbaging imageview at: " + position);
    View view = (View) o;
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView(view);
    view = null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to put on manifest inside application android:largeHeap="true"

It resolves most of memory problems